# Permission Denied when Calling Shell Script from a Python Subprocess in Browser

Tags: python, ajax, bash, shell, cgi

I am calling a python script through an ajax call

```
$.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/username/test.py",
        type: "post",
        data: JSON.stringify({'param':{"hello":"world"}}),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        },
        error: function(error) {
        console.log(error);
        }
    });
```

The python script kicks off (have set up the conf files and have an apache server running) but then the python script is supposed to loop through a bunch of subprocess calls calling various shell files. Something like this:

```
for line in reader:
    var=line["A"]
    var2=var[:-4]
    var3=line["B"]
    print(var2)
    subprocess.call(["sh","dummy.sh",var,var2,var3])
```

The same python scripts works fine in terminal. But when I run through the web browser, I get permission a 500 error in the browser. Going into the apache logs, shows me its running into a permission error

> [Thu Jul 23 18:13:55.958161 2015] [cgi:error] [pid 19878] [client ::1:54132] AH01215: dummy.sh: line 37: inputFile.xml: Permission denied, referer: http://localhost/username/

How do I pass permissions? or am I doing something completely wrong here?

Comment: It looks like dummy.sh can't read inputFile.xml because of some restrictions. Try chmod 666 on the inputFile.xml. That gives all users and groups ability to read and write on the file.

Comment: @revolt, 666 is evil, and that is not a joke. Random users do not need write permission so 644 should be fine.

Comment: @rici Fair enough, but I did warn him of the risks :). I also prefer 755. It gives the owner all permissions, but others only get read.

Comment: Don't give x permission to a file which is not executable. It's not always wise to give x to random users either. Of course, for directories 755 is probably appropriate.

Comment: Thanks Revolt and rici. inputFile.xml is actually created within dummy.sh and then other steps within dummy.sh operate on inputFile.xml. I also anticipate that since I have already given other files in the folder 755 access, its these new formed xml files that are restricted. How do I ensure that all files created by dummy.sh have enough permissions that they can be executed upon? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Ok. So I just changed owner as recommended by folks on this thread. chown -R _www:_www /path/to/parent      This seems to be working now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you run the python script at the terminal, it runs as a process with your user ID, I assume?
If you can open the input file by doing this, then it is most likely a permission issue.

The apache process just isn't privileged enough to open the file.

I'd suggest:

- Check the owner and permission of the file - make sure it is readable by the Apache process userID. This requires the file to at least have read permission, ie. -rw-r--r-- (chmod 644).
- Also don't forget the directory path permission and/or ownership.
  eg. if the file is in /home/foo/bar/inputFile.xml, you need to check that the whole path /home/foo/bar is accessible by the Apache user. This requires at least drwx--x--x (chmod 711) on the directories.

Comment: Thanks Maelstrom. I have given a+x as well as 755 permission to all files in that folder. Both the python and shell scripts are in the same folder. I even verified using ls -l and they have the right permissions. I suspect its using a different user. As per my httpd.conf these files should be using _www user and group.

Comment: Is the whole folder path from / accessible by apache/httpd user? You need to make sure the full path is accessible (711, or rwx--x--x), not just the folder where the python and the script sits.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Maelstrom, Revolt and rici. inputFile.xml is actually created within dummy.sh and then other steps within dummy.sh operate on inputFile.xml. I also anticipate that since I have already given other files in the folder 755 access, its these new formed xml files that are restricted. How do I ensure that all files created by dummy.sh have enough permissions that they can be executed upon? Thanks a lot.